# How to replace values of a row in a particular column

Tags: python

so i am kind of stuck here, my data is something like this

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'X': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1],
                   'Y': [6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 9, 8, 7, 6],
                   'Z': [11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 14, 13, 12, 11]})
```

id like to write a code to set the values of the rows 6 to 9 of the column 'Z' to NaN.

the best ive come to do is:

```
df.replace({'Z': { 6: np.NaN, 7: np.NaN }})
```

but all this does is replaces values for the new value if set in column Y.

i am confused as to how to change the values of the rows in a column if some values are same in that particular column.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `loc` indexer for your dataframe. I've used column 6 to 8 because `df` doesn't have a column 9:

```
df.loc[range(6, 9), 'Z'] = pd.NA
```

Answer (score 1):

you could use:

```
df.Z[6:9] = np.NaN
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you should use `.iloc` for this.

First of all, the index is zero based, so there is no row 9.

To change the values from row 5 to 8 on column 'Z' to pd.NA you could do something like this:

```py
df.iloc[6:9,2:] = pd.NA
```

I'm assuming Pandas > 1.0 which introduced NA values.